# UILabel and UIButton - truncate label instead of button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, truncate, xcode9

In my app I have a UITableView with a custom cell which contains a dynamic title label and a button next to it like in the following screenshot:

[image: my custom cell]

My problem is when the `Title` label gets too long, the button is truncated.

Instead i want the label to be truncated and the button should always be fully displayed. How can i achieve this?

(I do not want to set a fixed width for the button, since internationalization has to be supported too)

Comment: Set minimin font size for UILabel .

Comment: Set minimin font size for UILabel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the priority of the constraint between `label` and `button` as 250 (low) . And set one more constraint which is trailing space from your title label to superview which should be little bit greater than button's width . Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

1) set a fixed width to  `button`

**Note: The button would be truncated in this case**

2) Set Fixed Width to `label`

if you will set a fixed width to `label`, it would be same for `iPad` so it looks very ugly

[image]

you need to manage width based on `UIScreen`, If you set a fixed width to `label`

3) Using `Content hugging priority` and `Content compression resistance priority`

- Set Following Constrain For `label`

  set horizontal 250 in `Content hugging priority` and 749 in
  `Content compression resistance priority`

  [image]